# Is there a way to stop an upgrading script, like ISServer_upgrade.sql from running? MSSQL 2019

Tags: sql-server-2019

I have looked into this, https://www.sqlservice.se/script-level-upgrade-for-database-master-failed/

SSISDB has been removed so I would hope the upgrading script wouldn't do anything.

Maybe recreate a new SSISDB.

Comment: The linked article include troubleshooting instructions and a possible fix. Have you tried the suggestion in that article? If it didn't work, please [edit] your question to add additional details regarding the error messages you are getting related to this script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I was able to uninstall the SQL CU, delete the SSISDB(don't need) and reinstall the CU and it all worked.